# How can I execute a command and immediately quit the terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal

It should be pretty clear what I'm trying to do:

original script.sh:

```
select blah in foo bar oof rab
do
  cmd $blah
  break
done
```

Pretty basic stuff.  The problem arises when I try the following:

```
> xterm -e 'script.sh'
```

script.sh works just fine when called from a shell.  But when I try to call it from fvwm, I see no results from "`cmd $blah`".  Trying the following modification does nothing for me:

```
select blah in foo bar oof rab
do
  nohup cmd $blah > /dev/null 2>&1 &
  break
done
```

How can I achieve the desired functionality?  (that is, how can I make an xterm pop up long enough for me to do a select, then kill itself while a command runs in the background?)

Comment: "Do a select" - do you mean that you want the script to run, output to the terminal, then you select/copy the output, and then it closes the terminal?

Comment: @Paul Not exactly.  I would like to launch (not from a shell) a script that briefly opens a terminal long enough for a script with select logic (requiring kb input) to execute a background process and then immediately close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add as the very last line of your script a **wait PID** instruction with the `PID` of the background command you are interested it will finish. Of course you have to store that `PID` in your script.

```
#!/bin/bash 
# do first stuff...
select blah in foo bar oof rab
do
  cmd $blah &
  PID_TO_WAIT_FOR=$!  # here you store the PID of the last command
  break
done
# do other stuff 
wait  $PID_TO_WAIT_FOR
```

Notes:

- wait is a shell builtin command. *It waits for each specified process to complete and return its termination status.*   You can refer to this [help](http://ss64.com/bash/wait.html).

Answer (score 1):

Will it suit you if you run it in a new `xterm` session and then exit from your current terminal? It should leave the new one still working.

`xterm -e "bash -c \"./script.sh; exec bash\"" &`

EDIT:

The approach bellow allows you to run script from GUI in terminal, select command to run, leave terminal and have command still working. As an example I put some command in commandscript.sh

selectscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash Menu Script Example

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Option 1")
            echo "you chose choice 1"
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            echo "you chose choice 2 HEXDUMP"
            nohup bash commandscript.sh 
            ;;
        "Option 3")
            echo "you chose choice 3"
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

commandscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec hexdump /dev/urandom | grep --line-buffered -i "ffff f" > random &
```

Comment: Does as advertised, but does not solve the original problem.  :)  I want an xterm to exist just long enough for the script to run (with my stdin-put)

Comment: I added some info into edit.